# When I minimize my browser the background color doesn't follow my picture

Tags: html, css, background, minimize, responsiveness

I am working on my school activity website, I try adjusting my background size where it needs to be responsive just like the pictures that I put but when I run the code it doesn't follow the images. I also tried to put media queries but it just didn't work, please help.

here is the html & css code:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
 /* project*/

 #project {
   background: #033541;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}


.project-title h2{
    color: white;
    font-size: 75px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    text-align: center;
   font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.gallery {
   padding: 30px;
   position: absolute;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   width: 98vw;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(230px, 230px));
   column-gap: 15px;
   row-gap: 15px;
}


.gallery img {
    
   border-radius: 10px;
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
 }
```

```html
<!----project start---->
<div id = "project">
    <div class = "pro">
        <div class="project-title">
        <h2>PROJECT</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
        <img src = "image1.jpg" />
        <img src = "image2.jpg" />
        <img src = "image3.jpg" />
        <img src = "image4.jpg" />
        <img src = "image5.jpg" />
        <img src = "image6.jpg" />
        <img src = "image7.jpg" />
        <img src = "image8.jpg" />
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `height: auto` for `#project` and change `position: absolute` to `position: relative` for `.gallery` .

Because making `position: absolute` without any parent element with `position: relative` tells that these elements are positioned according to viewport(or screen), they don't relate to parent element.
So height is spanned to parent element only without taking them into consideration

> If you just remove `position` and add `height: auto`. It will also work

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
 /* project*/

 #project {
   background: #033541;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}


.project-title h2{
    color: white;
    font-size: 75px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    text-align: center;
   font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.gallery {
   padding: 30px;
   position: relative;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   width: 98vw;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(230px, 230px));
   column-gap: 15px;
   row-gap: 15px;
}


.gallery img {
    
   border-radius: 10px;
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
 }
```

```html
<!----project start---->
<div id = "project">
    <div class = "pro">
        <div class="project-title">
        <h2>PROJECT</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
        <img src = "image1.jpg" />
        <img src = "image2.jpg" />
        <img src = "image3.jpg" />
        <img src = "image4.jpg" />
        <img src = "image5.jpg" />
        <img src = "image6.jpg" />
        <img src = "image7.jpg" />
        <img src = "image8.jpg" />
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
```